# Is there any way to determine whether a linux executable is using soft float on an ARM processor?

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux

Is there any way to determine whether a linux executable is using soft float on an ARM processor?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the ARM [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (EABI) version, there is a processor-specific flags for ARM that indicate the floating point behavior in the `e_flags` field of an [`ELF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) header.

From Linux/arch/arm/include/asm/elf.h

```
#define EF_ARM_SOFT_FLOAT       0x00000200      /* ABI 0 */
```

EF_ARM_SOFT_FLOAT   - use FP instructions(0) libcalls (1)

There are programs such as [readelf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) that can be used to display information about ELF files.

Answer (score 0):

is there something in /sys or /proc that tells you what processor it is, you could possibly determine from the processor family/type if it has a floating point unit.

Comment: I believe *dwelch* may be refering to **/proc/cpuinfo**.